# Apache2 webserver ubuntu 16.04 not allowing any page besides index.html

Tags: html, apache, ubuntu, server

I'm attempting to add multiple html pages to my website.

I've pasted the files into `/var/www/html` which is what my virtual hosts file is pointing to. However, whenever I try to navigate to another html page such as `domain.com/page.html` it fails to find anything.

I feel like I'm missing a setting or something with `apache2` that is preventing me from accessing anything but the `index.html`. I've checked to insure the files are in the correct directory. I hope someone has some idea whats going on as I'm a bit lost.
heres the virtual host file;

```
<VirtualHost 72.222.165.39:7777>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly
ServerName www.birnbaumdesign.com
ServerAlias *.birnbaumdesign.com

ServerAdmin royce.birnbaum@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Which error code do you get? 403, 404, or something else? Also, do the Apache log files say anything useful?

Comment: Not found in bold. And the logs just had all the restarts of the service, no reference to the attempted connections.

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the right logs? There should definitely be a log of the error. Which log files did you look in?

Comment: here's the virtual hosts file, i'm 99% sure I just typed this wrong somehow

Comment: What do your access.log and error.log files say?

Comment: "GET /codercamps.html HTTP/1.1" 200 471 "http://www.birnbaumdesign.com/codercamps.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"